# Rally App Disappears - Why?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, rally

I currently have an app that has five components.  On the left I have a radio button field and a grid below it, on the right I have a display field, chart, and another grid [top to bottom].  The radio buttons filter every other component by a certain date, and the left grid [when selected] will filter the right components by the selected object.

Currently the app does what is needed, but when I select a few radio buttons in a row OR select a few objects in the grid, the app will eventually totally disappear.  I tried running the app externally and internally with a custom HTML app, but the problem does not go away.

Here is a picture of the app before anything crashes:

[image: App before crash]

Interestingly, when I look through the chrome debugger and look at the Elements tab, I see there are lots of masks that have been created and not destroyed.  Here is a picture of a slight piece of the HTML that looks fishy and occurs after I select a few objects from the left grid:

[image: Masks that keep getting injected into the HTML]

Every time I select a new object, one more mask will be added to the DOM.  I don't know if this is what breaks my app, but it seems odd so it may be related?

I didn't include any code because I thought it should be some easy fix - plus, the code does exactly what it should [before it disappears].  Any help on how to fix an app that disappears would be great!

Answer (score 0):

In itself a mask sticking around to be reused after data loaded successfully is not an indication of a problem. I see mask being created and not destroyed in a simpler app:[image]

Perhaps what you experience is an issue of timing when elements load asynchronously.

Comment: Cool, hopefully that means the masks are not the problem.  I did put console.log() statements at the beginning of every function to see if they were called out of order, but they seemed to be called in the correct order.